# Hypothesis testing (parameters)

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

I am new to statistics, but familiar with basic concepts. The lecture that confuses me is Hypothesis testing. Although the idea behind it seems ok, I couldn't understand the first exercise I found.

**Exercise**:

> Average time of execution of computer program is 45s. We want to buy a better PC so we tested that program on 30 other PCs and got average time of 44.5s and standard deviation 2. Based on these assumptions, should we buy a new PC?

**Result from the book**:

> $$H_0:m=45$$
>   $$H_1:m<45$$
>   $$n=30$$
>   $$\overline{X_n}=44.5$$
>   $$\overline{S_n}=2$$
>   $$T_n=\frac{\overline{X_n}-m_0}{\sqrt{\overline{S_n^2}}}=\frac{44.5-45}{2}=\sqrt{30}=-1.3639$$
>   $$W=\{T_n<c\}$$
>   $$p=P\{T_n<\overline{T_n}\}=0.0907$$
>   p is greater then alpha so we accept hypothesis null hypothesis

**My understanding**: 
We want to prove that we shouldn't buy new PC because it runs as long on the others average, and alternative hypothesis says that we should buy a new one. So I don't understand what the last three rows, from Tn to p. Can you please tell me what is the idea behind this?

Comment: You don't know whether to reject the hypothesis or not until you calculate the $p$-value.  In this case the $p$-value is $0.0907$ and we only reject if $p<0.05$ so we don't reject.  You don't know that until you have calculated $p$.

Comment: But how do we know that the threshold is 0.05 for disqualification?

Comment: It is a commonly used significance level. However, it *should have been specified*  in the problem statement.

Comment: This makes it clearer now. I just have to ask, why is this formula for Tn used? Are there any others depending on the problem?

Comment: The $0.05$ threshold is a pretty common convention, also common are $0.01$ and $0.001$.  It just depends on how willing you are to make a mistake.  In buying a computer you might be willing to make the mistake one time out of 20, while if testing a drug you probably would want a much smaller $p$-value.  As for $T_n$, that's just the so-called $T$-statistic.  It's one rather common way to test such a hypothesis but there are like a hundred other ways, and there's no proof of which is best, that's what makes it an ugly business.

Comment: Also to be clear, you can think of the $p$-value as the probability of observing the data you observed, given the null hypothesis is true.  If your null hypothesis makes the data unlikely then you reject it.  On the other hand a Bayesian approach would consider the probability of the hypothesis given the data.  There's a lot of debate about which approach is better with little to no agreement.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Thank you very much for the thorough and simple answer. I understand it now.

Comment: @Filip No problem.  Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

Comments:

(1) I believe there is something wrong with the following equation
in your Question.

$$T_n=\frac{\overline{X_n}-m_0}{\sqrt{\overline{S_n^2}}}=\frac{44.5-45}{2}=\sqrt{30}=-1.3639.$$

You say that the 'standard deviation' of the sample is 2. Using the usual definition and notation, this means
$$S = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2}{n-1}}.$$
Then the $T$-statistic for your problem would be
$$T = \frac{\bar X - 45}{S/\sqrt{n}} = \frac{44.5 - 45}{2/\sqrt{30}} =  -1.369306.$$

I believe you may be using the notation $\sqrt{\overline{S_n^2}}$ for the
'standard error' $S/\sqrt{n}$ of $\bar X$, not for the 'standard deviation' of the sample. Also, the part with "$= \sqrt{30}$" may be the result of a
mistake in typesetting--easy enough to make with such a 
complicated formula. Finally, many statistics texts use $\mu_0$
instead of $m_0$ to denote the hypothetical value of the population
mean.

Anyhow, the result $T = -1.369306$ is OK. And then the p-value is
0.0907 (not significant), as in the useful comment by @GregoryGrant. In R statistical software, this 
computation is as follows:

```
 pt(-1.369306, 29)
 ## 0.09070778
```

Below is output from Minitab statistical software for the problem.

```
 MTB > Onet 30 44.5 2;
 SUBC>   Test 45;
 SUBC>   Alternative -1.  # indicates alternative is 'less than'

 One-Sample T 

 Test of mu = 45 vs < 45

                             95% Upper
  N    Mean  StDev  SE Mean      Bound      T      P
 30  44.500  2.000    0.365     45.120  -1.37  0.091
```

The 'upper bound' is for a one-sided confidence interval.
Roughly speaking, it indicates that the population mean is likely below 45.12.

(2) There is a difference between 'statistical significance' and
'practical importance'. Even if you had rejected the null hypothesis
that new computers take 45s to run your program in favor of the
alternative that they are faster, what does that mean to you?
Your best estimate of the speed of new computers is 44.5s. Are
you willing to buy a new computer for half a second difference
in running time for such a program? That is not really a direct
statistical question, but a personal one that depends on your
needs and finances.